# CSS: I don't have horizontal scroll but when I click and drag the page it goes left

Tags: css

I'm developing a website and on its home page I have some sliders.
When I use these sliders I used to get horizontal scroll. I managed to fix that using overflow-x:hidden; at the css for the body element.

My problem is that When I click and drag the page to the right the scrollbar doesn't appear, but the user have the same effect as if he was using the scrollbar.

I received the html/css from a third part front-end developer and I'd prefer not to have to modify his css much.

Would you have any tips to fix this behavior without having to do further changes in the html/css structure?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You wish to change the rendering of the page without changing the HTML and CSS that define this rendering?

Comment: are you able to post some sample markup?

Comment: The only event where is horizontal scroll is when an element is wider then it's parent. Therefore you either need to modify the child to be thinner or the parent to be wider. The side scrolling issue only seems to occur when you set overflow-x and not overflow; is there a reason you can't set overflow:hidden?